# What is the appropriate way to communicate Vert.x cluster with Orbit cluster?

Tags: vert.x, orbit

You should be careful with thread management when using [Vert.x](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x). I don't want to implement a whole new [Orbit](https://github.com/orbit/orbit) client for [Vert.x](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x). What is the appropriate way to communicate a Vert.x cluster with an Orbit cluster? Is it a good idea to use [Vert.x](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x) tcp eventbus bridge with an [Orbit](https://github.com/orbit/orbit) cluster?

Comment: What's the usecase? Do you have an existing Orbit codebase that you want to integrate with Vertx?

Comment: There is no existing Orbit codebase. Many devices will connect to vert.x and each device will have its own verticles (and state). These devices will subscribe some background services which are not always running. So I think virtual actor pattern fits better for my scenario instead of managing life-cycle and distribution of actors. Verticle to Orbit virtual actor subscription is what i need to achieve in a proper way. I suspect that using Orbit client in a verticle will block vert.x threads. I'm not expert with these tech stack but i'm highly interested in learning. Thanks for any help.

Comment: But you can use Vertx Hazelcast cluster for that. Send messages over EventBus to your worker verticles (background services, as you call them).

Answer (score 1):

There is no best answer here. Both options have pros and cons.

Using the tcp eventbus bridge will give you the quickest integration between different systems, however it has the downside of introducing a single point of failure. Say that the node that runs the bridge crashes or the network breaks you'll be isolated.

Alternatively (and a bit more complex) would be to implement a cluster manager based on orbit. One should start by looking at the interface [ClusterManager](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/spi/cluster/ClusterManager.html) and from there provide an orbit implementation. Since the whole cluster manager is an SPI at runtime (in the vertx side) one could just replace the implementation jar and no code change would be required. For a full documentation on this see [here](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_cluster_managers). The downside is that it will be more complicated to achieve but you'll have better integration.